# XSLT : copy a node depending of its value

Tags: xml, xslt

Given the following XML example file :

```
<A>
    <B>
        <elem1 att1="SN:" att2="toto" att3="tata"/>
    </B>
    <B>
        <elem1 att1="tata" att2="SN:" att3="toto"/>
    </B>
    <B>
        <elem1 att1="toto" att2="tata" att3="SN:"/>
    </B>
</A>
```

I want to perform an XSL transformation to remove the attributes which value is equal to "SN:", resulting in the expecting output :

```
<A>
    <B>
        <elem1 att2="toto" att3="tata"/>
    </B>
    <B>
        <elem1 att1="tata" att3="toto"/>
    </B>
    <B>
        <elem1 att1="toto" att2="tata"/>
    </B>
</A>
```

I can isolate elements with a condition when the same element has a matching attribute, but how can I isolate elements when I don't know which attribute is equal to "SN:" ?

Perhaps more accurate : I know how to isolate elements like *if att1 value = "SN:", then remove it*, but how can I just do *if attX value = "SN:", then remove it*.

I want to remove them so I can concatenate "SN:" with another value from another element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy everything *as is* using the *identity transform* template, and suppress any attribute with the value of "SN:" by matching it with an empty template.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*[.='SN:']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Ooh, fast and correct answer ! Works like a charm, I didn't expect to have an answer this evening but thanks to you, I can finish my task before leaving work :) Thank you !