# XSLT : concatenate attributes with unknown names

Tags: xml, xslt

Following [my last answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33216701/3726044), I am now trying to delete two attributes and creating a new one using their concatenated values :

**Input :**

```
<A>
<B>
    <elemX att1="SN:" att2="toto1" att3="tata" SerialNumber="123X" />
    <elemY att1="SN:" att2="toto2" att3="tata" SerialNumber="123Y" />
</B>
<B>
    <elemX att1="tata1" att2="SN:" att3="toto" SerialNumber="456X" />
    <elemY att1="tata2" att2="SN:" att3="toto" SerialNumber="456Y" />
</B>
<B>
    <elemX att1="toto1" att2="tata" att3="SN:" SerialNumber="789X" />
    <elemY att1="toto" att2="tata2" att3="SN:" SerialNumber="789Y" />
</B>
```

**Desired output :**

```
<A>
<B>
    <elemX SerialHarnessNumber="SN:"123X att2="toto1" att3="tata" />
    <elemY SerialHarnessNumber="SN:123Y" att2="toto2" att3="tata" />
</B>
<B>
    <elemX att1="tata1" SerialHarnessNumber="SN:456X" att3="toto" />
    <elemY att1="tata2" SerialHarnessNumber="SN:456Y" att3="toto" />
</B>
<B>
    <elemX att1="toto1" att2="tata" SerialHarnessNumber="SN:789X" />
    <elemY att1="toto" att2="tata2" SerialHarnessNumber="SN:789Y" />
</B>
```

The order of the elements doesn't really matter here.

To do so, I use the following XSL :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*[.='SN:']" >
    <xsl:attribute name="SerialHarnessNumber">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('SN:', @SerialNumber)" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@SerialNumber" />
```

For the moment, I only managed to display "SN:" in the *SerialNumber* attribute, but the *SerialHarnessNumber* doesn't concatenate with it, though I used the *@* before *SerialNumber*, a syntax which worked previously on another XSLT.

I assume the problem comes from the fact that the *SN:* value is never in the same element.

How can I concatenate the *SerialNumber* value with the *attX* value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*[.='SN:']" >
        <xsl:attribute name="SerialHarnessNumber">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('SN:', ../@SerialNumber)" />
            <!-- _______________________________^^^               -->
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@SerialNumber" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Almost, indeed... It works, thank you very much ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `../@SerialNumber` to select the parent element's attribute.

Comment: Same solution as accepted answer, but 3 minutes later... Thank you too :)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be simpler?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@SerialNumber">
    <xsl:attribute name="SerialHarnessNumber">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('SN:', .)" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*[.='SN:']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That's another way which works fine too, thank you for sharing it ! It has the same effect on the output file, except that the attributes are sorted. As the output file is not supposed to be read, the order is not really important, but I save your solution for further projects ;)

Comment: The attributes are not really "sorted". I just thought it would be more straightforward to fix the attribute that already has the significant value. As a result, the serial number keeps its existing place. -- BTW, the XML specification states explicitly that the order of attributes has no significance.

Comment: But it is more comfortable if you need to look directly at the XML content, which is not the case here. Thanks for the explanation :)